# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Tags: c#, file

I am testing and learning about `System.IO` in c#, in my program I ask the user for some text to write in a file, store it, and then use `File.WriteAllLines()` to write them in a file. This however shows a error saying :

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Here is my code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Write Some text");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
File.WriteAllLines("Text.txt" , text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `File.WriteAllText("Text.txt", text);` which takes a single `string` value:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Write Some text");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
File.WriteAllText("Text.txt" , text);
```

The error is telling you that `File.WriteAllLines` expects the `text` variable to be some kind of collection of `string` (e.g. an array, list, etc.) that it can iterate through. As you have a single `string`, this won't work.

Alternatively, if you plan to read many lines from the Console and write them at once, you could generate a list:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) // repeat 5x
{
    // read a line from the console and add it to the list
    lines.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}
File.WriteAllLines("Text.txt", lines);
```

Now `WriteAllLines` will work because `List<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Documentation:

- [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0)
- [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-5.0)